# Java Heap Sort and Counting Sort returns false

Tags: java, sorting, heap

I have an assignment where I have to implement heap sort, quick sort, and counting sort into my program. Currently I have no errors but my output is returning as false for my heap and counting sort. What mistakes am I making? How can they be fixed? Please help any feedback will be appreciated.

```
package sorting;

import java.util.*;

public class Sort2 
{

    public static int left (int i) 
    {
        return 2 * i + 1;
    }

    public static int right (int i) 
    {
        return 2 * i + 2;
    }

    public static int parent (int i) 
    {
        return ((i-1)/2);
    }

    public static void max_heapify (int[] array, int heap_size, int i) 
    {
            int largest = i;
            int l = left(i);
            int r = right(i);

            if (l < heap_size && array[l] > array[i]) 
            {
                largest = l;
            }
            else 
            {
                largest = i;
            }
            if (r < heap_size && array[r] > array[largest]) 
            {
                largest = r;
            }
            if (largest != i) 
            {
                int exchange = array[i];
                array[i] = array[largest];
                array[largest] = exchange;

                max_heapify(array, array.length, largest); 
            }
    }


    public static int[] build_heap (int[] array) 
    {
        int heap_size = array.length;
        for (int i = array.length/2; i >= 1;i--) 
        {
            max_heapify(array, heap_size, i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] heap_sort (int[] array) 
    {
        build_heap(array);
        int heap_size = array.length;
        for (int i = array.length;i >= 2;i--) 
        {
            heap_size--;
            int exchange = array[0];
            array[0] = array[heap_size];
            array[heap_size] = exchange;
            max_heapify(array, array.length, 1);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void quick_sort (int[] array, int p, int r) 
    {
        if (p < r) 
        {
            int q = partition(array, p, r);
            quick_sort(array, p,q-1);
            quick_sort(array, q + 1,r);
        }
    }

    public static int partition (int[] array, int p, int r) 
    {
        int x = array[r];
        int i = p - 1;
        for (int j = p;j< r;j++) 
        {
            if (array[j] <= x) 
            {
                i++;
                int exchange = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = exchange;
            }

        }
        int exchange = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = array[r];
        array[r] = exchange;
        return i + 1;

    }

    public static int[] counting_sort (int[] A, int k)
    {
        int [] C = new int[k+1];
        int [] B = new int [A.length];
        for(int i = 0;i <= k; i++)
        {
            C[i] = 0;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
        {

            C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            C[i] = C[i]+C[i-1];
        }
        for (int j = A.length - 1;j > 1; j--) 
        {
            B[C[A[j]]- 1]=A[j];
            C[A[j]]=C[A[j]] - 1;
        }
        return B; 
    }


    public static int[] generate_random_array (int n, int k) {
        List<Integer> list;
        int[] array;
        Random rnd;

        rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
            list.add(new Integer(rnd.nextInt(k+1)));

        Collections.shuffle(list, rnd);

        array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            array[i] = list.get(i).intValue();

        return array;
    } 

    public static int[] generate_random_array (int n) {
        List<Integer> list;
        int[] array;

        list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
            list.add(new Integer(i));

        Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            array[i] = list.get(i).intValue();

        return array;
    }

    /*
     * Input: an integer array
     * Output: true if the array is acsendingly sorted, otherwise return false
     */
    public static boolean check_sorted (int[] array) {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i-1] > array[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void print_array (int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int k = 10000;


        System.out.println("Heap sort starts ------------------");
        for (int n = 100000; n <= 1000000; n=n+100000) {
            int[] array = Sort2.generate_random_array(n);
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            array = Sort2.heap_sort(array);
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long t = t2 - t1;
            boolean flag = Sort2.check_sorted(array);
            System.out.println(n + "," + t + "," + flag);
        }
        System.out.println("Heap sort ends ------------------");


        //Currently works
        System.out.println("Quick sort starts ------------------");
        for (int n = 100000; n <= 1000000; n=n+100000) 
        {
            int[] array = Sort2.generate_random_array(n);
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
             Sort2.quick_sort(array, 0, n-1);
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long t = t2 - t1;
            boolean flag = Sort2.check_sorted(array);
            System.out.println(n + "," + t + "," + flag);
        }
        System.out.println("Quick sort ends ------------------");


        int[] array2 = Sort2.generate_random_array(10, 10);
        array2 = Sort2.counting_sort(array2,10);
        boolean flag = Sort2.check_sorted(array2);
        System.out.println(flag);

        System.out.println("Counting sort starts ------------------");
        for (int n = 100000; n <= 1000000; n=n+100000) {
            int[] array = Sort2.generate_random_array(n, k);
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            array = Sort2.counting_sort(array, n);
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long t = t2 - t1;
            flag = Sort2.check_sorted(array);
            System.out.println(n + "," + t + "," + flag);
        }
        System.out.println("Counting sort ends ------------------");

    }
}
```

**EDIT** I modified your check method to print out the offending array elements:

```
   public static boolean check_sorted( int[] array ) {
      for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
         if( array[i-1] > array[i] ) {
            System.err.println( "Reversed array elements: " + (i-1) + "=" 
                    + array[i-1] + ", " + i + "=" + array[i] );
            return false;
         }
      return true;
   }
```

It looks like the heap sort does not sort the first element of the array:

```
Heap sort starts ------------------
100000,5,false
Reversed array elements: 0=100000, 1=99999
```

And ten more like that.

Comment: I modified your check method to print out the offending array elements, it looks like heap sort is consistently skipping (not sorting) the first (0th) array element.

Comment: In your `heap_sort`, you have `for (int i = array.length;i >= 2;i--)`. You're off by 1. It's just a counting loop. Why not use `for (int i  =0; i < array.length; ++i)`? If you insist on the count-down loop, change `i >= 2` to `i > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For this homework assignment I would have suggested doing a google search on the specific sorts you were told to complete.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

This will show you the code you just need to modify it for your variables.  One thing I noticed right away is you are not building the count array correctly and that is affecting the build of the output array.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/

Here is the same instruction and explanation for your heap sort.  I did not really look deeply into this as I do not have the time right now.  Please use these resources to modify your code and hopefully complete the project.